# Spring messaging + security how to login throught websockets?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, stomp, spring-messaging

I am developing a server with spring-messaging and STOMP over sockJs.
I want to make authorization trhought websockets.
So from client i did send some token, then i get needle user by token and i want to associate my session with this user, i did next:

```
private void authorizeUser(Profile profile) {

    SignedUser signedUser = new SignedUser(profile);
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(signedUser, null, authorities);


    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
}
```

But session is not associated, can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem, how are you sending the token from the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below links. Spring Security 4.0 allows out of the box support for Web Socket.

https://spring.io/blog/2014/09/16/preview-spring-security-websocket-support-sessions

http://spring.io/blog/2014/08/21/preview-spring-security-websocket-support

Comment: I try to implement, but get `Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.session.SessionRepository org.springframework.session.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.sessionRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository]`

Do you have any suggestions?